# Given a set of images to be identified, and a trained model, how would I make the model identify the images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How can I make a trained model identify images I extracted from somewhere else?

The model is trained with the MNIST dataset, and the images to be 
identified by the model are handwritten digits extracted from a document.

Libraries used are `tensorflow 2.0`, `cv2`, and `numpy`.

As I understand, `model.predict()` identifies its input. By that, I mean if I input a handwritten image of '3' there in some form, it will identify and output '3'. Again, this said `model` is trained with the MNIST dataset based on [this set of tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/quickstart/beginner).

Assuming it is, I'd like to know the parameters of the function or how would I format the image/set of images to get my expected output. If not, I'd like to know how I would exactly accomplish this.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Load and prepare the MNIST dataset. Convert the samples from integers to floating-point numbers:
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def createModel():  
  # Build the tf.keras.Sequential model by stacking layers. 
  # Choose an optimizer and loss function used for training:
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

model = createModel()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

c = cv2.imread("./3.png", 1)
c = c.reshape(-1, 28*28)/255.0

# now what?
```

I expected `model.predict()` would do this what I needed. So far this is my attempts:

`model.predict(c)` outputs `TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'`

`model.predict([""], c)` outputs `ValueError: When using data tensors as input to a model, you should specify the`steps`argument.`

And so on.

I know at this point I'm going in blindly and incorrectly. Any step to the right direction is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

So I know the input image `c` should be a grayscale 28x28 even before reshaping, so I tried skipping that. Error that came out when I implemented prediction is:

```
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [28,28], In[1]: [784,128]
     [[{{node dense/MatMul}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_2593]
```

So I used `c = c.reshape(-1, 28*28)/255.0` before prediction, but then it never predicted the right value of any digit.

I then tried to use `cv2.imshow(str(predicted_value), c)` to show what the input image would look like. The shown image is just of a thin line of black and white spots. As I still can't link images yet, [here is the link to the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ST1.png) instead.

My question is, is this what the image is supposed to look like for the model? Or that I may have messed it up? Thanks!

Comment: What is the shape of `c`?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in the sample code. `txt` should be `c`, so `c` should be a 1-channel 28 * 28 image, which is the same shape of an individual MNIST image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your model is trained with gray scale images it expects the input image to be gray scale. 
RGB image has 3 channels. Gray scale image has only 1 channel.

So, when loading the image instead of **1** which stands for **cv2.IMREAD_COLOR**, use **0** corresponding to **cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE** to load the image in grayscale mode.

(NB: Use **-1** for **cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED** Refer to the opencv documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html) for more details)

```
yourimage = cv2.imread("yourimage.png", 0)
```

For predicting, after reshaping you can use:

```
predicted_value = np.argmax(model.predict(yourimage))
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! However, it never got a single digit correct. Please see the following edit in my post since it's too long for a comment. Again, thank you!

Comment: The accuracy of prediction is a metric of how good your neural network architecture is and it also depends on your train/validation data. You will have to tune your neural network in such a way that you generalize well by adjusting the hyper parameters such as number of layers, type of layers, learning rate, optimizer etc. In your case I don't think 5 epochs is enough for the model. Try increasing it above 100. What were your validation accuracies?

Comment: So the input image isn't the issue? By the way, if what you meant by validation accuracies is the output of `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)` after training or loading weights, then it is at the least, 0.97. I will try what you said. Thank you!