# How would I improve my model such that it will work on more characters not in the dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In my last post linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797855/given-a-set-of-images-to-be-identified-and-a-trained-model-how-would-i-make-th), it was said that I have to modify my model for it to be better. To quote the only answerer's comment to my questions (again, thank you, Sir):

> The accuracy of prediction is a metric of how good your neural network architecture is and it also depends on your train/validation data. You will have to tune your neural network in such a way that you generalize well by adjusting the hyper parameters such as number of layers, type of layers, learning rate, optimizer etc. ...

I would like to know how I would do these mentioned. Or at the least, be pointed in the right direction. I am honestly both lost in theory and practice.

The only thing I have been able to do is to adjust the epoch above 100. I have also cleaned the images to be identified as much as I can.

Currently, here is how I create my model. It is only based on Tensorflow 2.0's tutorial.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Load and prepare the MNIST dataset. Convert the samples from integers to floating-point numbers:
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

def createModel():  
  # Build the tf.keras.Sequential model by stacking layers. 
  # Choose an optimizer and loss function used for training:
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  return model

model = createModel()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=102, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

It gave out a validation accuracy of around .9800 for me. But its performance against images of handwritten characters I've extracted from documents is dismal. I would also like it to be extended such that it can also read other selected characters, but I guess that can be another question for another day.

Thanks!

Comment: By using a CNN, your model will be more robust to translations (which is only part of the problem you are facing, handwritten numbers are less likely to be exactly at the center of the frame). Also, you might want to create a little validation set of handwritten digits as a validation set.

Comment: I apologize for necro'ing this question, but what do you mean with that? And how would I do so?

Comment: This tutorial explains it in details: https://www.kaggle.com/moghazy/guide-to-cnns-with-data-augmentation-keras The main idea behind **CNNs** is that your network has a (or multiple) **sliding window(s)** that is going to **scan your image** to recognize patterns, that way, it will perform better with characters that are not centered. You might want to check out **data augmentation** as well, it might help with your problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have multiple layers of **Convolution/ Max Pool** at the beginning that would perform a feature extraction by scanning the image. After that you use a fully connected NN like you did before and a softmax.

You could create a model with a **CNN** that way:

```py
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout 
from keras.models import Sequential 

# Create the model
model = Sequential()

# Add the 1st Convolution/ max pool
model.add(Conv2D(40, kernel_size=5, padding="same",input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))) 

# 2nd convolution / max pool
model.add(Conv2D(200, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))

# 3rd convolution/ max pool
model.add(Conv2D(512, kernel_size=3, padding="valid", activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))

# Reduce dimensions from 2d to 1d
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(units=100, activation='relu'))

# Add dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Final fullyconnected layer
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax")) 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 

print(model.summary())
```

Which returns the following model:

```py
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 28, 28, 40)        1040      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 14, 14, 40)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 200)       72200     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 200)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 512)       922112    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 32768)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               3276900   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1010      
=================================================================
Total params: 4,273,262
Trainable params: 4,273,262
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Any other improvement or tips to improve its accuracy on characters not in the dataset? I've tried running it again on my test document, and while it got slightly better results, it still didn't get the majority of the images..

Comment: You could add [data augmentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) to your training pipeline, by adding distortions/warps to the images you feed into the network, it will improve the recognition of the images. But the best way would be to have a **training dataset closer to the images you want to recognize**.

Comment: I've just finished training my new model with data augmentation and ran it up on my sample document, took it about 12 hours to finish training, and while it got a lot more correctly, it still got the majority incorrect. Also, I am not that confident I did data augmentation correctly, so I might just ask a new question. Maybe it's time to admit the handwriting's terrible? Anyway, thanks!