# Am I doing data augmentation correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I was told that using data augmentation would help me get more accurate predictions on handwritten digits I've extracted from a document (so it's not in the MNIST dataset I'm using), so I used it in my model. However, I'm curious if I did it correctly, as the size of the training set before using data augmentation is 60000, but after adding data augmentation it went down to 3750 per epoch? Am I doing this correctly?

Following the data augmentation part of [this tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/moghazy/guide-to-cnns-with-data-augmentation-keras), I've adjusted it such that it will work on how I create and train my model. I've also left out optional parameters in the functions that I don't really understand as of the moment.

The current model I'm using is from one of the answers I got from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849555/how-would-i-improve-my-model-such-that-it-will-work-on-more-characters-not-in-th) as it performs better than the second model I've cobbled together for the sake of trying. I think the only change I made is to make it use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead for loss, as I'm categorizing digits and handwritten characters can't belong to two categories of digits, uh, right?

```py
def createModel():
    model = keras.models.Sequential()

    # 1st conv & maxpool
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(40, (5, 5), padding="same", activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    # 2nd conv & maxpool
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(200, (3, 3), padding="same", activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1,1)))

    # 3rd conv & maxpool
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding="valid", activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(1,1)))

    # reduces dims from 2d to 1d
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=100, activation='relu'))

    # dropout for preventing overfitting
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    # final fully-connected layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Training is done by a separate function, and this is where I plugged in the data augmentation part:

```py
def trainModel(file_model, epochs=5, create_new=False, show=False):
    model = createModel()

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1)) / 255.0
    x_test = x_test.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1)) /255.0

    x_gen = np.array(x_train, copy=True)
    y_gen = np.array(y_train, copy=True)

    datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, featurewise_std_normalization=True, rotation_range=20)
    datagen.fit(x_gen)

    x_train = np.concatenate((x_train, x_gen), axis=0)
    y_train = np.concatenate((y_train, y_gen), axis=0) 

    # if prev model exists and new model isn't needed..
    if (os.path.exists(file_model)==True and create_new==False):
        model = keras.models.load_model(file_model)
    else:
        history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train), epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
        model.save(file_model)

    if (show==True):
        model.summary()

    return model
```

I would expect it will greatly help with correctly identifying the handwritten characters assuming it was used correctly. But I'm not even sure if I did it correctly such that it contributes a lot on the model's accuracy.

EDIT: It did help a bit in identifying some of the extracted characters, but the model still didn't get the majority of the extracted characters right, leading me to doubt if I have implemented it properly..